# video not found or access denied

Tags: flash, server-configuration

I have made a website in ASP.NET 3.5 With C#.In the default page we have a swf player.We have one video file.The file format is .mp4.

The Code is here:-

type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

id="player2"

name="player2"

src="images/player.swf"

width="350"

height="280"

allowscriptaccess="always"

allowfullscreen="true"

flashvars="file=../images/vtwsub.mp4"

/>

The problem is that when i try to run this code on my local it runs but when i put the same code in clients Windows 7 server it says "video not found or access denied: ../images/vtwsub.mp4.

I have provided the full access of WWWROOT folder in the server but problem remains constant.I need to fix this issue very soon.I have tried to find some answer in google but not getting the exact ans.If anyone has any idea, please reply me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figure it out.In my case server issue was there.In this type of case you should check following things:-

1)video is properly placed in the right place.

2)Any name issue.(like misspell)

3)Check server permission.(some server will not allow to access those file.suppose you file is in mp4 format or anything else so try to convert in .swf  & then try to access.)

I really hope it will help you

Thanks.......

Comment: In your last point, you asked to convert to swf. Is it right or it supposed to be flv?

Answer (score 1):

if you have not solve your problem yet here is the solution,
don't put "player.swf" file under any sub directory try putting it in the root directory where your index.asp or index.php existed.

your structure:
src="images/player.swf"

Mine:
src="player.swf"

Regards,
Muzafar Ali

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a path issue. I would debug using Firebug or something similar to view the http traffic. There you might see a 404 occuring for the video, in which case it is most likely pointing in the wrong place (i.e. up or down one directory from the correct place)